# .css won't affect my template in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I am currently writing my first django-app and are encountering a few problems, as expected.

The problem I am struggeling with at this moment is linking css to my template files. I've been searching around stackoverflow, but nothing of what I find seems to work.

I am currently running django 1.4.2

In my settings, I have staticfiles app and staticfiles_finders enabled. My staticfiles_dirs looks like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/user/project/static/',
)
```

Inside my static folder I have a css folder where I store my css files.
In this case the path to my css file is this.

```
/home/user/project/static/css/index.css
```

In my template for my app, I've linked to the css file like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/index.css />
```

However, the css does not seem to affect my page. The css does however work if I write it directly in my template file so I assume I've linked it wrong?

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to use access the css directly using your browser?

Comment: Have you tried to open the browser's console and check if it actually finds the css file

Comment: Try: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/index.css />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.4+

```
{% static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
```

Note: If this code is not working, you should check your settings and urlconf. And I also notice some bad practice in your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way :

Edit these variables in the file **settings.py**

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(PROJECT_URL, 'static')
```

They are refering to absolute path to folders on your system, for example :

- PROJECT_ROOT --> /home/user/project
- STATIC_URL --> /home/user/project/static

Expand url from STATIC_URL variables :

- {{ STATIC_URL }} --> h ttp://(your_host)/static/
- {{ STATIC_URL }}/css --> h ttp://(your_host)/static/css